# How to make gopls recognize external github imports

Tags: vim, bazel, neovim, gopls

I recently started to work on a Go project.

When I use `gopls` with `Coc`, all external imports are not recognized such as `"github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"`. It complains it could not find this module from neither $GOROOT and $GOPATH.

This project is managed by `bazel`, and all depedencies are listed in `WORKSPACE` file. Do I have any way to install all packages based on WORKSPACE file or I have to `go install` all packages one by one? If the latter, I would imagine keep package version synced is challenaging.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same issue. For me, the problem was in `GOPATH` env variable. Make sure that you are exporting the variable in `~/.profile` for example.

The correct path for Go you can query like that: `go env GOPATH`